# LWC - render component onclick event

Tags: lightning-web-components, date, button, lightning-events, onclick

I have a lightning button and I have an instance of js Date class.

When I click on a button I want it to to show me a date that was week before (subtract 7 days).

Here is my .html file:

```
<template>
    <button class="slds-button slds-button_neutral" onclick={handleClick}>
        <label>
        new date
        </label>
    </button>
    {date}
    {test} <!-- for some reason this renders a new value together with date, but only on a first click -->
</template>
```

and here is my .js file:

```
import {LightningElement} from 'lwc'; 

export default class DemoCard extends LightningElement
{
    
    date;
    test;

    handleClick (event)
    {
        this.date.setDate (this.date.getDate () - 7); //shows desired date but only on a first click        
        this.test = this.date; //without test desired value doesn't render on click at all
    }


    connectedCallback ()
    {
        this.date = new Date ();
    }
}
```

**Why isn't new value rendered each time when I click on a button?**

Comment: The date's internal state is being updated and this isn't being noticed by the LWC framework. Have you tried using `@track date` when declaring the property? You'll need to import `track` along with the `LightningElement`.

Comment: @PhilW decorated the date property with track but nothing has changed :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Date is an object, not a primitive, so `this.date` holds a *reference*, therefore its value doesn't change when you run `setDate()`. That's why the framework doesn't rerender it.

[Reactivity for Fields, Objects, and Arrays](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/platform/lwc/guide/reactivity-fields.html) (emphasis mine)

> If a field’s value changes, and the field is used in a template or in a getter of a property that’s used in a template, the component rerenders and displays the new value. **If a field is assigned an object** or an array, **the framework observes some changes to the internals of the object or array, such as when you assign a new value**.

`@track` doesn't help here. It works only with plain objects created with `{}`.

In order to rerender it, you don't need `test`, you just have to create a new reference, so a new Date object:

```js
handleClick (event)
{
    this.date = new Date(this.date.setDate(this.date.getDate() - 7));
}
```

The first time, and only that time, it rerenders because `test` changes from `undefined` to the reference of `this.date`.
On every other click after the first, the value of `test` doesn't change.